# modular arithmetic - congruency

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Suppose $a$ is an integer, and $a\equiv 4 \pmod{13}$.

Find the $c$ with $0\leq c \leq12$, and

$c \equiv9a\pmod{13}.$

I'm mildly confused by this problem because I don't understand what the value of $a$ is. Can the value of $a$ vary? I have a whole list of problems to do and I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Please use latex in writing the equation. You can use a single dollar sign ('\$') or double dollar signs ('\$\$') to write the equation in a newline.

Comment: [Here is a brief introduction to MathJax (link)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), the equation writing command language used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the value of $a$ can vary, but only such that the given condition on $a$ is fulfilled. So $a$ can be $4$, $17$, $30$, etc., and also $-9$, $-22$, and so on.

The important part, though, is that $a$ leaves a remainder of $4$ when divided by $13$. What then is the remainder of $9a$, when divided by $13$?

Comment: You are a beautiful and wonderful person. Thank you so much. Will accept as answer when it allows.